# Pandas value_counts returning multiple lines for the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Running into an issue with Pandas where my dataframe value_counts call is returning multiple lines for the same values. Instead of grouping all "True" values and all "False" values, it's splitting them into 4 groups.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

filepath=r"C:\Users\09.41.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

print(df['Finished'].value_counts())
```

Output:

True                       3904

True                       1877

False                       190

False                        94

I want to be able to group all "True" and "False" responses together for analyses, but I keep getting stuck with these 4 groups instead of 2.

Running Python 3.7.4 and the CSV is directly from a survey software (Qualtrics).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: in all probability the `True` and `False` are strings that has spaces , try `print(df['Finished'].str.strip().value_counts())` may be ?

Comment: I think you're onto something. When I ran that, it returned "True 3904, False 190." How could I keep the Trues and Falses with spaces and combine them with the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your values data type. Some of the rows may be string and some of them may be bool. For example:

```
[True,'True','False',False,False]
```

If that's the case, change them all to bool and then count the values:

```
df.Finished.apply(lambda x: 'True' in x if type(x)!= bool else x).value_counts()
```

Comment: This helped me solve my problem! The column was an Object data type, so I forced it to bool and now I am receiving the correct value counts. Thank you so much!